# Why isn't this code working? It doesn't seem to be selecting the HTML elements properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

`

```
<!--jQuery--><script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<!--jQuery UI--><script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--jQuery UI CSS--><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
    function Alert(a){
    $("#p")[0].innerHTML = a;
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            $("#main").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: "auto",
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": () => {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    await Alert("test");
});
</script>
<div title="Message!" id="main">
    <p id="p"></p>
</div>
```

`

I'm wanting it to open a popup with the popup title of Message! and with the text of test.
I've tried so many things to fix this but I can't.
I've come to the conclusion that it's not selecting the elements properly.

Comment: try using `autoOpen: true` you are using `false`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest:

- The first thing I noticed is that there is no `async` on the left of function on your document ready. Try adding `async` and see if it solves the problem
- Or may by try to combine that 2 script tags into one
- If it still doesn't work, try logging it out with `console.log()` or regular `alert()` on your value, see if it's even return something at all. Maybe that `$("#p")` doesn't need the first index to be accessible because it is an id, not a class

Comment: The async thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> conclusion that it's not selecting the elements properly

That's not correct, your code is working fine. Just that the dialog is not opened because `autoOpen` is set to `false`.
I tried this code, hope it helps:

(also I don't think you need Promise)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div title="Message!" id="main">
    <p id="p">Paragraph to change!</p>
  </div>

  <!--jQuery-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <!--jQuery UI-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!--jQuery UI CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script>
    function Alert(a) {
      alert("a: " + a)
      $("#p")[0].innerHTML = "I have changed!";
      $("#main").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: "auto",
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
          "Ok": () => {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            resolve(true);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    $("document").ready(function() {
      Alert("test");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Just one thing not related to your error though just informing you so you will remember this, this code is actually not right

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    await Alert("test");
});
```

The await keyword is only valid inside async functions within regular JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite right way... hope it helps!

Any questions, just ask and I'll answer in the comments.

```html
<!--jQuery--><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<!--jQuery UI--><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--jQuery UI CSS--><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(() => { 
    const Alert = (param) => { 
      const $dialog = $("#dialog");
      $('#targetContent')
        .html(param)
        .ready(async () => {
          $dialog
            .dialog({ 
            autoOpen: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
              "Ok": () => {
                $($dialog).dialog("close");
                return resolve(true);
              }
            } 
          });
        })
      ;
    };
    Alert("test");
  });
</script>
<div id="dialog">
    <p id="targetContent">Old content</p> 
</div>
```